# Why Universe was unstable when Lord Brahma created it?

Tags: history, creation

It is said that Lord Vishnu entered universe to make it stable. Why Universe was unstable when Lord Brahma created it?

Comment: Lord Vishnu was born inside this universe(Hiranyagarbha) so there is no point in him being entering it, outside of this Hiranyagarbha, only Maha Shambhu and Adi Parashakti exist.

Comment: I have heard that Lord Brahma threw water upwards and it created lokas. Not sure for authentic source.